# How do I make sure that the animation on an activity works more than just once

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am currently doing a basic Whack a Mole game on Android Studios for a school project. I got everything pretty much working, including the moles moving up, and down when clicked.
The problem is whenever a game is ended and I choose to "play again" the game activity starts again with the timer and everything, but the mole animation no longer works.

Whenever the game ends I change activity to a game_over activity where the user can choose to play again or return to the main menu.
This is all I am doing to change activity:

```
public void change_to_game_over_activity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Game_Activity.this, Game_Over_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I am guessing I am not properly ending the animation when changing activities because I thought when the user presses play again, the activity was going to start everything from zero.

What functions can I use to properly transition to the game_over activity and back again to the game activity if the user chooses to?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! Try finishing the current activity when you move to the game over the screen. Call `finish()` after `change_to_game_over_activity `. That way your game activity screen will be started from scratch. I suppose this can help

Comment: @Ivan Shafran your answer helped, I also needed to clear some arrays. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by calling finish(), and clearing all the arrays containing the mole images when on the onStop() callback.

Answer (score 0):

*Your Activity closed then please finish() method*

```
public void change_to_game_over_activity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Game_Activity.this, Game_Over_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent); finish();
}
```